# jquery i18n - is there a way to send url with specific translation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internationalization, i18next

**My problem:**

My url: *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*
My default translation is let's say japan.

When user clicks button, page translates to en but url remains *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*.

Is there a way to send this link with en transaltion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use get like : www.example.com/en/ (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.
The less intrusive in my opinion is something like this: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3

The used [i18next-browser-languageDetector](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector) there is also able to detect the language based on querystring or url path.

But to do some server side stuff I would suggest to use: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware